# error in building a nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/deThread/dethread-demo-applications) github project to work. These are the steps I followed

1. cloned it using `git clone <url>`
2. Execute `npm install` inside the new directory
3. Execute `npm run build`
4. Finally start the server with `npm start`

But step 3 gives errors regarding missing files and directories. Is there any step I'm missing?
If possible can anyone run it and confirm the error?

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./components/App in /home/terry/dethread-demo-applications/src
 @ ./src/index.js 11:11-38
```

Comment: Maybe there are other pre-requisites that aren't listed.

Comment: Your path isn't good the script can't found your module file or directory.

Comment: What should I do in that case?

Comment: @headmax App folder doesn't exist in components folder.

Comment: @kendall did you look in that .zip file?

Comment: @Pointy it's working thank you very much